# functional component disappears while using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I just wanted to make a simple project setup with `react-router-dom` but whenever I'm using `route` the entire page becomes blank. my Nav disappears. why ?

there was a similar question for class component so it wasn't helpful for me.

App.js :

```
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import About from "./components/About";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
        <About />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nav:

```
import React from "react";
import Navstyle from "../styles/Nav.module.css";
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav className={Navstyle.Nav}>
      <ul className={Navstyle.nav_links}>
        <li>
          <a href="!#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="!#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="!#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

other components are just returning `h2` tags

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a layout (as a HOC) to add a navbar or other things to your code.
just use the components with routes in your router.
I recommend defining the Layout in another file.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Router>
        <Route component={Products} path="/products" exact />
        <Route component={About} path="/about" exact />
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  );
}

const Products = () => {
  return <p>Products</p>;
};

const About = () => {
  return <p>about</p>;
};

const Navbar = () => {
  return <p>navbar</p>;
};

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, how can I do that ? you meant I should do the same routing stuffs in Nav.js

Comment: I tested it. but it didn't work

Comment: same. disappears

Comment: updated the answer, please first test my code after that refactor it as your needs

Comment: I guess I find out. check my own answer ! lol I'm answering to my own question

Comment: it's just like my previews answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I find out ! the problem was YouTube videos I guess. first of all you must add `BrowserRouter` to your index.js **not** `app.js` , like this :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

after that you must use react router in that way , not the way I tried first :

```
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import About from "./components/About";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

during the changes of `react-router-dom` in version 6 , this is the new way of using router.
the link of docs :
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview